# Are Kenneth French Research Returns log-Returns?

Tags: data, returns, fama-french, log-returns

Does anyone know if Kenneth French's return data on his [website](http://mba.tuck.dartmouth.edu/pages/faculty/ken.french/data_library.html) is log returns?

Comment: I wrote him to ask on 12/31/2018 and immediately got a reply: "Our returns are simple, not natural logs."

Comment: @MikeO'Connor Thanks Mike!!!!!````¬¬¬¬

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No, none of the returns on Kenneth French's [data library](http://mba.tuck.dartmouth.edu/pages/faculty/ken.french/data_library.html) are log-returns.**

Any of the Fama/French research factors (i.e. SML, HML, etc.) is calculated as the mean of value-weighted portfolio returns. The description for the 3-factor calculation states:

> The Fama/French factors are constructed using the 6 value-weight portfolios formed on size and book-to-market.

,which holds for other factor-returns as well.

The returns of the industry-portfolios are given both as monthly and yearly return series, calculated as equal-weighted returns as well as value-weighted returns. This information can be obtained wether within the download file or its corresponding description page.